# How to set the caret position at the end of the text?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I want to set the caret position to the end of a Text after appending text to a StyledText.

How do I achieve this? Set caret at the end of the text

This is in continuation to my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615475/how-to-enable-autoscroll-for-a-styledtext-component/8615532#8615532)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to my question.

I tried this, but this was not preferable to me.

```
styledText.selectAll();//moves the scroll bar down but selects all text.
```

This worked for me!

```
styledText.setSelection(styledText.getCharacterCount());
```

My gratitude to all for the above answers.

Answer (score 6):

I have never used StyledText but looking at the [API](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/StyledText.html) shows a method called `setCaretOffset( int offset )` which takes a number that is the offset from the beginning of the text. So you could call `getText()`, find its length, and then set the caret to be that number as the offset.

*I like the answer that Travis posted below. I didn't notice the method getCharacterCount() on StyledSheet. That is probably a little cheaper then getting the text then the length.